# HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type error on tryign to DELETE Session ID in JMeter

Tags: types, performance-testing, media, jmeter-plugins, http-delete

The Request Header for the http request taken from development tool is shown below
[Request Header in developer Tools for the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHy0S.png)

I tried to use many things in JMeter in the HTTP Header Manager, but the call results in Error HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type. This is occuring while deleting the session id

[Header Manager from JMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wNWB.png)

DELETE Method works fine for other operations with same header paramater
any suggestions.

Thanks,Puja

Answer (score 0):

Your `Request Header in developer Tools for the URL` doesn't show full request headers.

According to [HTTP Status Code 415](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) description:

> The HTTP 415 `Unsupported Media Type` client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an **unsupported format**.
>
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) or [`Content-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding), or as a result of inspecting the data directly.

So make sure to configure the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) to send exactly the same `Content-Type` and/or `Content-Encoding` headers as the browser does and ensure that the request data is the same and the error should go away.

---

Going forward given you're capable of sending a proper request by browser you should be able to capture it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) which should be smart enough to capture all the needed headers (apart from [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)) and add them to the HTTP Header Manager